# Pentaho Reports- To migrated to alternate BI platform

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, pentaho, migrate, pentaho-report-designer

I have few business reports in Pentaho and it seems that these should be moved into a different platform altogether. These reports have measures, there's bar representation and look quite complex.

The options available are Power BI and SSRS.

My question is to understand if there are any plugins available in SSRS or PowerBi for me to import the files from Pentaho directly or should  have to build these from scratch?

Comment: i was involved in SSRS to pentaho report migration project sometime back. we created reports from scratch and as per my knowledge you need to create from scratch

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with Pentaho and these reports are too complex, with options to dynamically pull in columns/measures